# Removing someone else's "Thank you!"

Tags: discussion, edits

I just saw a user make this edit: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25067193/revisions

The only thing that changed was that the editor removed the word "Thanks" from the end of the post.

Are edits like this really necessary or constructive? It might make sense if the OP had written "PLZZZZZ SEND TEH CODEZ!" or something else that is either unprofessional or distracting, but in this case it seems like a harmless thank you to other users for taking the time to read and answer the question.

Furthermore, an edit like this really seems too minor and could almost be construed as borderline abuse of the editing system.

What are your opinions on edits like this? Is this behavior harmless and not to be worried about, or is it more serious than that?

Comment: Regarding your follow-up, I simply say to these folks "Wait until you have 2000 rep, and then you can make these kinds of edits without getting community approval for them."

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree with your sentiment, but who's going to tell that to the new users? I'm worried that many of them will try to emulate the behavior of more establish users (I know that I myself strive to do that wherever I can), even if it's not yet appropriate.

Comment: I guess they figure it out or they don't, just like everything else here.  Like it or not, we've favored efficiency over consistency in this particular case.  Note that the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) specifically states "Your edits should be substantial."

Comment: From the Uber-Meta: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/476162)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

"Thanks" is just noise.  An edit that is removing it is an edit that is removing noise, which is a good thing.

You are of course correct that this is a fairly minor change, however, even though it is a positive one.  Minor edits are noticeably more concerning with suggested edits, due to all of the extra work involved in evaluating them by experienced reviewers.  For users with full editing privileges minor edits aren't really that bad.  Yes, it would be better if this change was just one part of a larger change (and there were indeed other things to fix, see the subsequent revision), but it's not exactly all that harmful either.

It's certainly not abusive.

Comment: It's sad that good manners are considered 'noise'.

Comment: @Ryan Saying, "thanks" is not automatically good manners, nor is not saying it automatically bad manners.  Good manners are contextual; they are the behaviors that are considered appropriate in a particular situation for a particular community.  On SO, it is considered *good manners* to *not* say "thanks".  It is considered poor manners to say "thanks".  You wouldn't expect to see "thanks for reading this" at the end of each entry in an encyclopedia, would you?  Does that make the author rude?  No.  It's a context in which saying "thanks" just isn't appropriate.

Comment: "Noise" ?! If every sentence in the question ended with "Thank you" then, sure, that could be regarded as "noise". But I seriously doubt a single, polite and courteous "Thank you" at the end of the post is going to throw anyone off the gist of the question!

Comment: Is there some kind of *ideal* on SO for us to try and devolve our behaviour so it matches that of the machines that we are programming?! I mean, most of know how to write a proper question, but to be discouraged from expressing a harmless mark of appreciation at the end of a question seems a bit sad.

Comment: @ban-geoengineering Did you not read my comment at all.  It's *not* being polite and courteous.  On this site that's *poor* manners.  Different communities have different norms, ideals, values, and as a result, different behaviors are considered rude here than might be the case elsewhere.

Comment: @Servy I read your comment, but I don't agree with it. An encyclopedia is very different to SO - esp. when the SO author is asking for help. Whilst seeing "Thanks" at the end of every encyclopedia entry would be inappropriate, I don't think the same for SO because it is an extremely different collation of knowledge. That's because it largely relies on people helping one another - so I don't personally think "Thanks" is out of place at all. There appears to be a convention on SO, but If I saw an appreciative "Thank you" at the end of most questions, I still don't see what harm it is causing.

Comment: @ban-geoengineering And yet the vast majority of the regulars of the site *do* feel that it's inappropriate, and that has become the expected behavior on this site.  You may not like it, but that is what this community has decided is appropriate.

Comment: @Servy "the vast majority of the regulars of the site do feel that it's inappropriate" - Even if this is true (I've never seen any sort of poll which supports the claim), it's a self-perpetuating reality.  Those who believe in normal human behavior are disinclined to become regular site users upon suffering the tyrannical over-moderation that this site has become infamous for.

Comment: @Servy: Can you please provide some data/discussion to prove your point?

Comment: @IvanSchwarz Which point?

Comment: @Servy: Vast majority of the regulars of the site feel that it's inappropriate to end an SO question with a thank you note.

Comment: @IvanSchwarz http://i.stack.imgur.com/dYJKW.png (You're free to look at other posts on this topic to see that they're consistent in this way, if you need more data.)

Comment: **7 chars is NOT Noise**! I believe it **in**appropriate to Delete "Thanks" *particularly* from **low rep users'** posts!! *This in itself* feels like a **slap-in-the-face** to a new OP who *is* kind, considerate, and gracious for any help. This act alone *promotes rudeness* AND **discouragement**. New editors rapidly gaining status via Search & Destroy "Thanks" :(( sets a precedence for editor to *"correct"* people unnecessarily, and sets a rude bias to their edits and posts. Frequent users will understand that it is normal to leave off "Hi"/"Thanks", and will leave it off. KINDNESS MATTERS.

Comment: "Thanks" and "Hi" give contextual reference that this is a **New User**, and likely new a **New Programmer**. This helps set OP's frame of reference, personality, and helps set the tone on how to answer. These subtle clues can be important, when communicating via text. Let's provide a culture that is **welcoming** to new users and **new programmers**. Remember too, women are taught they *must* reach out this way - Don't Shut Them Down at "Hello"! A user with *review privileges* removing "Hi"/"Thanks" from **high rep posts**: I'm OK with that: OP is a Seasoned programmer by now, and gets it.

Comment: Finally, there is a WHOLE lot of "noise" in questions. There is also a WHOLE lot of RUDENESS in Questions, Comments, Answers. Those are edits worthy of "fixing", and addressing.  A little "Hello", "Thanks" is a SMALL and WELCOME way to balance out such rudeness prevalent on this site.  Editing to alter the OP's personality, and Intent of a question is generally inappropriate.  It amounts to editing the way an OP chooses to word their sentences, when it is *not necessary* for *clarity, grammar, understanding, readability*, etc. Granting (low rep) points for altering a person's intent is Not Ok.

Comment: .. and contributes to the god-like toxic culture we see in tech.  Don't touch that common cultural nicety on posts of low rep users.  Don't grant low rep users points for removing said niceties.  PLEASE.

Comment: @SherylHohman You appear to be under the impression that this is a free personal tutoring service where everyone just personally tutors the person asking a question and then the question goes away.  That's just not true in the slightest.  The site is a place to create a repository of knowledge of programming information.  Every question is designed to be the canonical source of information for the answer to that one question asked, sticking around and helping every other person that has that problem in the future.

Comment: Ensuring that the questions and answers are as useful as possible to those future readers is the goal of the site.  Being kind and considerate to them is the goal here, rather than not valuing them or their time by forcing them to wade through pleasantries between others just to figure out what the question is asking or what the answer is.  Being rude and inconsiderate to those users is a problem, a problem addressed by editing questions to remove their noise.  They don't care that the OP is new, they care *what the question is*.

Comment: "[...]Or sometimes, everything actually goes well, and they get an answer! So they thank the poster… only to be told that on Stack Overflow, “please” and “thank you” are considered noise. All these experiences add up to making Stack Overflow a very unwelcoming place for far too many." [This(posted by the official SO Blog)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) might be worth a read to everybody, who thinks a simple "Thank you" is noise.

Comment: @Servy _You appear to be under the impression that this is a free personal tutoring service_. No, it is a place where **humans** interact.

Comment: @10Rep If you're looking for a place to socialize with people and exchange pleasantries, there are lots of places for it, but that's not what SO is here for.  Not every place that humans interact is there to socialize and exchange pleasantries.  You seem to have completely disregarded the rest of the comment you quoted.  This isn't a 1-1 interaction, it's creating a repository of knowledge.  The appropriate language one should use is different between the two.

Answer (score 34):

Once you reach around 2000 reputation, you stop getting extra reputation from having edits be approved.

Those users don't have to waste other people's time when they make an edit because they don't need their edit to be approved in the first place.

The user that made the edit you've linked is one such user.

Because of this, he's not grinding reputation, wasting people's time, nor is he making the post worse in any way.

There's no harm done whatsoever.  It's not a problem.

Comment: Well, it does bump the post, which is a bit of a problem, especially if such edits are done en masse.  But it's a very small problem, especially if it's just one isolated edit.  And of course if the post is already at/near the top of the activity lists then the effect is reduced all the more.