# Got approved and rejected for pretty much the same edit (removing thanks)

Tags: discussion

Should I or should I not edit questions like I attempted here?

[Rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6337671)

[Approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6337952)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267384/removing-someone-elses-thank-you

Comment: TL;DR: Editing hugely old posts in such minor ways - even if it's in a *correct* way - isn't really worth anyone's effort.

Comment: @J.Steen I disagree. There's a mountain of content on this site which could do with improvement. Google isn't only interested in results on the front page. If someone is willing to go to the effort of tidying up old content, why not let them do so? It improves the site as a whole, even if you think it's too unimportant for your time.

Comment: @Basic - Did you look at the edits? Do you honestly find [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6337952) to be anything but a waste of four people's time?

Comment: @MartinSmith No... And I agree I should've. My mistake. I believe my point is valid for users who have enough rep to make a change without filling up the approve edit queue. It's been a while since I've needed edits approved so I commented without thinking in enough detail. I agree that making others approve minor edits is a waste of resources [vote reversed]

Comment: @J.Steen SE disagree with you also, has [minor edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor) are to be approved if they improve, even so slightly, a question or answer.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau My beef - or that of the post I was paraphrasing - isn't "too minor". It's "too minor" and "sodding ancient" and "reviewed". There's no need to make such minor edits to such old posts and put it into the review queue.

Comment: @MartinSmith I find this argument hard to follow. It's not like the suggested edit queue is constantly overflowing and we're struggling to find people to do reviews. We're in almost the exact *opposite* situation.

Comment: @MartinSmith It doesn't seem like much of a waste of time when the content of the edit is so clear and easy to review. What is it, one click? Also FYI: I didn't go out of my way to find something to edit; I was looking for a solution to a problem and saw that I could make an improvement when I stumbled upon these questions. The indefinite amount of people looking at the question in the future will be spared the  trouble of reading off topic content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official say on this [is yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238039/227881).

But I'll leave it to you to decide if you want to keep doing it or not, and to decide, have a look at the numerous discussions about [minor edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=minor+edits).

Sometime those kinda of edits will pass and sometimes they won't, really depends on the people reviewing as many don't see these edits as good ones still.