# What to do when a high-rep user is willfully breaking site rules/meta consensus?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette, rules

AFAIK we have both a behavioural rule (https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), quote:

> Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.
>
> Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers.

*and* a meta consensus about salutations ([Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)). I understand that there are situations where you can nicely fit some greetings to compose with the Q/A without explicitly fluffing it (as saying "I'd be grateful if someone could explain me why it doesn't work." - it's still kind-of fluffy, but not as directly as "Explain to me why it doesn't work. Thank you for your answers!") - still, AFAIK, adding a one-liner after each-and-every Q/A is just, by definition, fluff to be removed.

OTOH, we have a user (namely
https://stackoverflow.com/users/501557/templatetypedef), who contributed about 3000 Q&A, *essentially almost all of which* are followed by either

> Hope this helps!

(for answers)

or

> Thanks so much!

(for questions).

As per what Jon Skeet has said - `I choose a world where strangers try to convey information rather than impersonal greetings (they're not really saying "Hi" to me)`; those greetings/salutations above are mechanically added by the author after almost *each and every post*. For me, that constitutes both fluff & noise.

I've seen that in some cases (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4589622/revisions) there have been some attempts (e.g. by https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit) to make his (templatetypedef's) answers/questions adhere to the consensus. Overall, it's still:

- about 3000 posts (some of them with very high view counts) needlessly fluffed,
- a high-rep user who breaks the rules/consensus willfully.

I believe in community, in meta discussion and in democratic consensus. I think that on SO nobody should be "more equal than equal"* and exempt from the rules (soft and/or hard) every regular user should/must adhere to.

Note 1: I've commented to him and edited those salutations manually for a couple of his top posts - he ignored the comments and reverted all the edits. Note that e.g. LRIO's edits *weren't* removed.

Note 2: I wouldn't have raised this problem at all if not the fact it's about >100k rep user. Such a user makes *an example* - other people (e.g. newbies) will often *follow* him.

Note 3: quote from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267387/719662 for those who responded that "removing salutations/fluff" is "harassing and/or abusing a user":

> "Thanks" is just noise. An edit that is removing it is an edit that is removing noise, which is a good thing. (...) It's certainly not abusive.

<sub>*[Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) doesn't count</sub>

Comment: Well, it's their right to reject your edits.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so you're basically saying "he can write whatever he wants, regardless if it's OK with the rules and site's consensus"?

Comment: Well, there's a choice to make: 1) Do nothing and live with taglines that annoy a small minority of users. 2) Warn/Suspend/Ban the 100k user - possibly resulting in a rage-quit and loss off a great contributor. Personally, I think the choice is pretty easy. We're not talking about someone who repeatedly attacks another user. It's just a stupid tagline.

Comment: @Mystical if a contributor ignores the site's rules and consensus, he's by no definition "great". Making exceptions to the rules just to *not annoy a good user* is IMO what elitism is all about. If he's a smart person, the warning should work. I'm against bans/suspensions for soft (community) rules, but breaking them makes a person work *against* the community, not *for* it. If someone rage-quits just because he's told to *adhere to the community consensus*, his place is on self-hosted blog, not a community site.

Comment: Although I'm a low rep / low frequentation user, and even though I fully understand and absolutely back up the idea of "information over fluff" as a primary driver for SO, I feel that the line that delineates the start of fluff does not need to be autistically enforced under such circumstances : if the user has such high rep, it's because he's flooded the place with useful content. Under those conditions, finishing a large post of heavy payload with one line polite greeting is no fluff ; it's rather the glue that holds unrelated human beings together, and I very much appreciate reading one.

Comment: @vaxquis, let's be pragmatic here -- if that user really has posted ~5K posts with these taglines, they cannot possibly edit them all (it would literally take years). So it looks like this situation is here to stay, even if we manage to somehow coerce them into not repeating that behavior in the future.

Comment: If a user is rolling back appropriate edits you should flag the post for mod attention and explain the situation.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi for me, it's not about *forcing him to edit them* (although it's not true that'd have taken years - that could've been done in minutes by a database script) - it's about him *not reverting those changes* and *understanding the consensus*; also, it's about "should we make exception to the site-wide rules for high-rep users?"

Comment: @Servy in all honesty, I hoped a mod could've seen this post and stated his opinion here.

Comment: @vaxquis In all honesty whenever you have a problem that you need a mod to look at you should flag the post rather than creating a meta post.  That's the *appropriate* way to get a moderator's attention for a problem with a post.

Comment: @vaxquis: in case it's not obvious, can you hold off editing any more of this users posts until this is resolved on meta. I'm not taking anyone's side with this request, I just want to end the edit -> revert wars that are going on between the two of you at the moment.

Comment: @Matt exactly. That was my idea from the very beginning.

Comment: @Servy see Matt's comment about this - if I were 100% sure I'm right on this one (e.g. newbie acting against hard rules), I would've called a mod instantly. If, however, I think it's a dispute between me and someone about how the rules should be treated - I think that a meta discussion is completely in place. I don't want to try to force my views on anyone, I just want the rules to be just that, rules.

Comment: For what it's worth, the rule about tag lines isn't just a Meta consensus, it's in the rules in the help center: [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: @BSMP thanks, I didn't even knew that part got there!

Comment: I've always felt the rule against salutations and thanks was a bit exaggerated.

Comment: @S.L.Barth the rule has been made *by the people, for the people* - if it's "exaggerated", it's so *intentionally*, to be a benefit to the community, not a nuisance. I'm not arguing with the rule here - it may be right, it may be wrong - I'm trying to know *should high-rep users be exempt from the rules - and, if so, *on what grounds**.

Comment: What rep is required for a user to reject an edit on their own question or answer? I doubt it's "high rep."

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I understand where you're coming from. And I agree that all should be held to the same standard. The rule itself dates back to the early days of Stack Overflow, though, when SO was working hard to create a good signal-to-noise ratio. It's a good rule, but IMO also one of the least important.

Comment: As for information over fluff, you're right, but this is a trivial problem relative to so many SO questions being repeats posted by new users in their first CS class.

Comment: @KevinB - You can reject an edit on your own post regardless of your reputation level.

Comment: Then i don't see what rep has to do with this question then.

Comment: @KevinB see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301016/what-to-do-when-a-high-rep-user-is-willfully-breaking-site-rules-meta-consensus?noredirect=1#comment230068_301020 for some background info. Short answer is: high rep & highly active (1000s of contributions) user has a much higher impact on the site, by the very fact that he created a bigger part of it.

Comment: Right, but i don't think the user's rep or number of contributions has any impact on what should be done here. It's just as jaring to edit 10 posts of a user with 200 rep as it is someone with 400k.

Comment: The rejected edit in this case should be handled just like any other rejected edit: either ignore it and move on, or flag for moderator attention if you feel it warrants moderator attention. I don't feel the tagline edit rejection in this case warrants moderator attention. It isn't harmful, and is only a minor improvement if at all an improvement.

Comment: @KevinB I too didn't think that it deserved mod attention, but since edit wars are wrong by itself, I thought it deserves a meta discussion. OTOH, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301016/what-to-do-when-a-high-rep-user-is-willfully-breaking-site-rules-meta-consensus?noredirect=1#comment230024_301016 ... also, the key problem is not just a high-rep user having 10 posts breaking the rules (in which case it wouldn't make a difference indeed) - it's about high-rep user having about (rough estimate) **5000** posts breaking the rules. That's something that 200 rep user can't beat.

Comment: @KevinB tl;dr I'm not arguing about the edits itself - they are only tangential here. Excuse me for repeating myself - I was wondering whether such behaviour of high-rep user should be tolerated or not, and on what ground. As you can easily see by the number of opinions presented here, the issue *ain't* simple in the sense that there *are* varying opinions on this matter. Thankfully the majority goes along the lines "Users are never above the rules", but there *are* valid voices about *why* some people could've been treated otherwise.

Comment: These signatures don't do any harm. how'bout you just leave the heck alone poor templatetypedef?

Comment: @vaxquis, as Shog9 [said](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268177/1476885): "stop going after individuals because you don't like something they wrote" and do not "Direct link to a user's profile". Your meta question is important, but public linking the user was a horrible ideia. It would be enough to explain the problem only giving numbers and quote examples without links.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I see you completely missed the fact they are a) against site rules, b) the rules were made *by the community, for the community*, c) they *do* harm - see the related meta discussion - just because you don't see or understand it, doesn't mean it's not there, d) somebody ain't "poor" because he breaks the rules. Would you say "these guys only stole two candy bars. petty crimes don't do any harm. how'bout you just leave the heck alone poor shoplifters?" ? Either rules are made to be obeyed, or they ain't rules.

Comment: @Zanon that's completely *against* meta style. I'm with Shog9 & Matt on *not* doing witch hunts. OTOH, each and every meta discussion requires *concrete* examples. I've already tried using "nameless placeholders" for the meta sake once - and got criticized directly for *not providing a real-life example or problem*. Also, you completely missed the fact I'm not going after an individual just because I don't like something they wrote. As I said, both the user and his posts are just examples. Also, you're misquoting and misunderstanding Shog9. He never said [don't] Direct link to a user's profile

Comment: @Zanon in case you missed it: the problem, as indicated by the title, is not "templatetypedef is a bad guy, let's lynch him", it's "What to do when a high-rep user is willfully breaking site rules/meta consensus?" - it's not about *liking* something, mate. I see the quality of most of ttd's answers/questions, they are *really good*. That *doesn't* change the fact he, well, is (or rather, I hope, was) willfully breaking site rules. What I asked is "what's the expected behaviour in such cases? should we make exceptions or not?" and stated "I'm against exceptions personally".

Comment: @vaxquis, ok, fixing: Shog9 didn't say "don't link" but said "watch out before linking". You didn't say "<user> is a bad guy, let's lynch him", but the mob started a witch hunt anyway.

Comment: @Zanon elaborating on Shog9's post: quote: `stop and ask if you could conduct a productive discussion without doing so` - in this case, IMO this was impossible. I could either just go to mods with this (which I didin't for the reasons outlined in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301016/what-to-do-when-a-high-rep-user-is-willfully-breaking-site-rules-meta-consensus?noredirect=1#comment230036_301016) - or open a discussion here *providing a direct trouble case*. Out of 3 "red lights" Shog9 described, I have only 1, and, arguably, I couldn't conduct a productive discussion without doing so

Comment: @Zanon well, there weren't any witch hunt here. Guy got 1 serial downvoter (votes will probably get reversed tomorrow) and GEOCHET removed the salutations from most of his handful of questions - but not from answers (AFAIK before Matt asked not to do so). That's hardly a "hunt" IMO. As a side note: at least two mods were here (Matt & Shog9), neither decided to remove the user's profile link from my post. For me, that's at least borderline acceptance of my decision to include it.

Comment: @vaxquis then maybe we should deal with more serious issues first, like question and answer quality.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant what can we do about problems like [overall site question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_overpopulation) and [answer quality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancer)? [Not much](http://www.shsforums.net/topic/13169-what-can-change-the-nature-of-man/), [I'm afraid](http://i1169.photobucket.com/albums/r507/svarun01/ban-everyone.jpg). OTOH, what can we do about the behaviour of a particular person? [Quite a lot](http://i1.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/065/311/BanHammer.jpg), [I think](http://i.imgur.com/Vsb2S.png).

Comment: Why is this even a thing? More time and bytes have been spent in this meta post then it has taken to write/store the phrase *Hope this helps!*  2802 times.

Comment: Lol this is absolutely ridiculous. I truly can't believe what this community is becoming. *Insert picture of Dolores Umbridge*

Comment: Based on this, https://stackoverflow.com/users/464581/cheers-and-hth-alf really needs to change his handle.

Comment: **Moderator note:** please take it to a chat room or leave this be. Your sniping back and forth is not constructive.

Comment: Take a deep breath and focus on what really matters

Comment: I think that "*Jon Skeet doesn't count" link you put at the end of the post is 10x worse then a simple "Hi" or "Thanks."

Comment: @EpicByte last time I checked, there weren't any community rules prohibiting [sense of humour](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/301022/revisions) - still, we have a ["lame denial"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301016/what-to-do-when-a-high-rep-user-is-willfully-breaking-site-rules-meta-consensus?noredirect=1#comment230078_301022) [proposal around](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301016/what-to-do-when-a-high-rep-user-is-willfully-breaking-site-rules-meta-consensus?noredirect=1#comment230086_301022).

Comment: I am a low frequency user, but hopefully the "all-are-equal" concept applies.  I think this is pure foolishness.  "hope it helps" on a site that is dedicated to connecting question askers with question answers just seems to me to be one of the most natural things that an answerer could post.  I officially cast my vote for "who cares, leave it alone".  edit:  if someone tags their post with :

David Coleman
Acme Inc.
555-444-1212

this is a violation.  "Hope this helps" is reserved, friendly and is a far cry from what I read the intent of prohibiting taglines to be.

Comment: Downvote any answers you see of theirs that have that fluff if they aren't removing it. Eventually they'll get tired of having -1 answers and stop answering (problem solved) or will change their posts to not have useless fluff (problem solved).

Comment: @TylerH That is an awful idea. Votes make answers more visible for the community. They should be about overall content and how well the answer solves the problem. The last thing we need is a vote-war.

Comment: @DavidColeman For me "hope this helps" conveys the meaning of "don't really know if this is the answer to your question, but I'll just throw it out there." This means the answer might not even need to be there, if the person isn't sure it will help. I know, not all answers can be 100% correct, but I'd rather use other ways to convey the uncertainty. For excample: "If the case is ... then this will fix it" is a lot better than "Do this ... hope it helps." But, opinions. For the actual matter I would say: rules are rules. There is no reason to let anyone reject edits to remove fluff.

Comment: @S.L.Barth. The *original* rule, and the rule I follow, was to edit out taglines, signatures, and thanks *only if there's also something else in the post that needs editing*.

Comment: Going around removing salutations and thanks from posts is one of the most anal-retentive attitudes I could ever imagine. Never greeting or never thanking is one thing; going around looking for greetings and thanks and removing them is completely another thing. Is this really how people want to spend their time ?

And downvoting posts that have that "fluff" ? Ever hovered with the mouse on the downvote button ? It says what the motivations for downvoting are supposed to be.

I also don't understand why "strangers" can either convey information or convey "impersonal" greetings but not both.

Comment: @EpicByte Only upvotes make answers more visible. Downvotes make them less visible. And technically, noise harms a message quality, so downvoting for fluff (noise) is not a bad reason, when considering the circumstances.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I think that your attitude is remarkably draconian.  When you are answering a stranger who may or may not have described their problem perfectly, then you can only "hope" that your answer is exactly what they were looking for.  After all, there are two huge variables at play: 1) the clarity with which they expressed their issue.  2) the accuracy with which you interpreted it.  therefore "hope this helps" is a perfect response.  Are you saying that nobody should answer anything unless they are 100% sure of their answer?  because SO afaik, accepts answers from ANYBODY!

Comment: @DavidColeman If you would have read my whole comment you wouldn't have to ask.

Comment: I did read your whole comment before I responded and I see nothing that changes my response.  maybe there is a better way to say it, but we are not here to dictate how another person chooses to express themselves.  how boring would it be to read the same cookie cutter expressions over and over.  Fahrenheit 451 comes to mind as an appropriate analogy to that.  anyway, i don't want to fight with you.  I just think that this is nonsense.  Leave the poor guy alone for cryin out loud.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen _For me "hope this helps" conveys the meaning of "don't really know if this is the answer to your question, but I'll just throw it out there."_ I hope you interpret that in that way only on bad days. Personally I remember a lot of answers ending with that phrase which were very good answers. Also, from the OP's description of the hi-rep user in subject: _...who contributed about 3000 Q&A, essentially almost all of which are followed by either "Hope this helps!" (for answers) or "Thanks so much!" (for questions)_. He/she most probably got a hi rep due to good answers.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Users are never above the rules and guidelines, whatever their reputation (or status).

To be blunt, this could have been handled better by both parties:

1. You could have brought to the attention of a moderator sooner, rather than targeting templatetypedef and taking it upon yourself to edit his posts, causing the issue to escalate to what it has become.
2. templatetypedef could have responded to your comments in the first place, and this could have been resolved more amicably.

... but those are lessons for another day, and what's happened has happened.

I've asked the user to stop using signatures going forward. I'm also asking you (and everyone else) to **avoid** hunting out all answers *ever* posted by this user, and editing out the signatures. Not least because he gets a notification for each post you edit, but also because this isn't a witch hunt.

Comment: -1 because you didn't open with "Hi,". Other than that, good answer

Comment: I got temped to add that "Hi!", but I figured I should've been smarted than to edit mod's posts *chuckle*

Comment: GEOCHET, you're a real fun killer... that was, like, a friday joke, on meta *duuuuh* can someone revert it?

Comment: @vaxquis the fun will begin when matt rolls it back

Comment: I didn't remove it because it was a tagline, I removed it because it was lame.

Comment: **News just in**: *What to do when a moderator is willingly breaking site rules/meta consensus?*

Comment: We have had those posts far too many times. Spoiler: They just delete everything and keep doing it.

Comment: @GEOCHET may I suggest adding "Don't be lame: every post you make is already “lamed” already*. If you use extraneous laming, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers. *unless you're Jon Skeet" to http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior ?

Comment: I wouldn't stop you.

Comment: So in the end the fluff stays in his answers (because you've explicitly asked us not to remove it)? That seems wrong.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam: No, he asked us not to hunt those down. If you come across them organically though, go ahead.

Comment: As a commentor says above, with 20 plusses, **"I've always felt the rule against salutations and thanks was a bit exaggerated"**.  It's really that simple.  As for this answer, it says "edit but don't edit".  So ...

Comment: @JoeBlow Yes, 20 people expressed that they feel the rule is exaggerated. Yet, unless you know how many people *don't* feel that way, you can't evoke anything from that number. I assume from the linked meta discussion that most of the people *don't* feel that way - otherwise there wouldn't be any way for the rule to get about +700 rating. On the other hand, I can say that 26 people expressed disagreement with your stance, while 2 people agreed - and that **is** statistically relevant. Also, this answer *doesn't* say "edit, but don't edit" - it clearly says "edit, but don't hunt".

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the two highest-pluss'd comments above are "it's just a stupid tagline" and "...was a bit exaggerated".  Regarding "edit but don't hunt", the "hunt" language is just a wiggle word.  If the text in question on the user's posts in question is "wrong", then **someone click to edit it away from every post**.  Could not be a simpler situation.  Of course, everyone here realises the rule is so incredibly silly you wouldn't expect children to follow it, and both the answers here are just non-answers which say: "oh, forget about it" with wiggle language.

Comment: @Joe Blow: Wait a second, speak for yourself. You do not have the knowledge about everyone. When I began reading the question, I was seriously interested in whether it is strongly enforced or not. I don't consider it to be silly. Don't ever go like "everyone shares my opinion anyway", it doesn't work.

Comment: @JoeBlow you're mistaken. Tho highest-pluss'd comments above are http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301016/what-to-do-when-a-high-rep-user-is-willfully-breaking-site-rules-meta-consensus#comment230018_301016 & http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301016/what-to-do-when-a-high-rep-user-is-willfully-breaking-site-rules-meta-consensus#comment230014_301016 (well, frankly it's http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301016/what-to-do-when-a-high-rep-user-is-willfully-breaking-site-rules-meta-consensus#comment230071_301022 *chuckle*)

Comment: @Deduplicator: I think they shouldn't even be edited if you come across them. They're old answers, and the edit is **too minor**. No need to bump the posts. Edit greetings out of active posts that need to be improved anyway.

Comment: @Bergi: Iff one comes across it organically, the post is still "active" as in "actively used", though that diminishes with low views and/or low votes. Still, I would only do an edit doing nothing but removing fluff even under those circumstances if 1. it was overwhelming, or 2. nobody has to review it and I did more worthwhile edits on other posts of the same question, or 3. I had a *good* reason to comment on that post and also did that. I think that's a reasonable guideline.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yeah, that sounds reasonable. Though I'd only consider case 2) as an "active" thread (where recently an action has happened), not only actively viewing it.

Answer (score 9):

As [@Mystical said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301016/what-to-do-when-a-high-rep-user-is-willingly-breaking-site-rules-meta-consensus#comment230014_301016), it's probably not worth the hassle to "correct" high-rep users who are going against the (maybe in their eyes silly) rules, as they'll probably leave and deprive the site of their valuable input.

If they've left thousands of posts with a tagline and actively roll back edits in which those taglines are removed, then please, let them be the first world anarchist they want to be seen as.

[image: First World Anarchy]

And no, I'm not serious. Every user should be held to the same standards. If they're going to leave because they can't say "Hope this helps" after every answer, then it's their loss.

Comment: now I'm puzzled... I can't figure where the irony starts and where it stops.

Comment: @vax come on, it's friday. My stance is _"Every user should be held to the same standards"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster if that's the case, may I kindly suggest a slight rewording of your answer, removing most of the irony, since otherwise a) it's hard to understand, b) it may receive erratic votes (as was a case with me).

Comment: I've heard from at least one moderator that when dealing with high-rep users, it's becomes a trade-off on whether it's "worth the hassle" to keep the user in exchange for all the users contributions. This means that there's inherent bias toward high-rep users and major contributors. I'm aware of at least one other major C++ contributor who has left SO after two suspensions over taglines. Sure the person didn't have a perfect personality, but I found his contributions very valuable and was sad to see him go. I would hate to see a repeat of that here.

Comment: @Mystical since it was neither Jon nor Eric, I think the universe will manage *chuckle*

Comment: @vaxquis those are the C# heroes, not C++ (at least not on SO). ;) Anyway I don't really want to rewrite my answer. I think it's really petty to want to either be allowed to add "Hope this helps" or otherwise leave the site, and I'm sure the guy who we're talking about here is mature enough to decide otherwise.

Comment: This principle applies pretty much any time someone has a high volume of mostly-useful contributions, @Mysticial, regardless of rep. See also the rules about self-promotion: folks tend to get far less upset if someone with lots of good answers throws a link to their blog in than they do when someone posts nothing but links to their site. Cheers & hth.

Comment: @Shog9 I figured you'd know exactly who I was talking about... (Edit: Looks like he came back. But not nearly as active as before.)

Comment: The picture here is perfect.

Answer (score -44):

"What to do when a high-rep user is willfully breaking site rules/meta consensus?"

1) the rule is silly

2) the salient point is: **"site meta consensus"** of pro-sumption sites like this is, simply, formed **by very-high-rep users, such as the user in question**.

So, it looks like 1x very-high-rep user is ignoring the ridiculous "don't say thanks" rule.  Let's say that ten or a dozen very-high-rep users were ignoring the "don't say thanks" rule.

In that case, the supposed "meta consensus" you refer to would be quite different.

Don't forget that the entire point of this pro-sumption dotcom business is to make money for the founders. Rules and "meta consensuses" change over time based on what - ultimately - most achieves that goal. Maybe there's a trend starting to throw in a bit of politeness and that will become a norm.

Looked at another way, what you're essentially saying here, OP, is: *"Hmm, I really like the 'no thanks notes' guideline from the old days ... I've noticed one or two high-rep users are moving the site away from that.  Shame, because I like that guideline..."*

Once again, if the site had 2, 3 and then 10 such very-high-rep users who were moving against this social norm ........... it wouldn't be a social norm anymore.

Thus to restate ... *"Such a user makes an example - other people (e.g. newbies) will often follow him or her."* ... well yes, of course.  That's what social norms are.  You're essentially just saying "you don't like his style" and you want newbies to follow "the style of people you do like".

Comment: The linked meta post has >+650 for the top answer affirming the general consensus. If you don't agree, you have the ability to vote it down. The meta site isn't only for high-rep users.

Comment: Why? One could easily assert that a few weenies discuss things on these "meta" sites.... "so what"?  As I mention above: as a thought experiment, imagine if 1, 2 then 20 very high rep users started adding "polite sign-offs" to posts.  And say it became a social norm.  In that case the existence of anything, one way or another, on the "meta" site would mean ... what?  Nothing.

Comment: From the Help Center: [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: 1. People are supposed to follow rules regardless of their opinions about said rules. Their alternatives are to campaign for a change in the rules, or break the rules and deal with the consequences. 2. If consensus were different, this user wouldn't be going against consensus, so that means he's not going against consensus, and therefore his style that no one else follows should be adopted as consensus? What?

Comment: I'm far from a very high rep user and feel I'm part of the consensus on such rules.

Comment: "if the site had 2, 3 and then 10 such very-high-rep users who were moving against this social norm" no... not at all actually. They would just get buried under the hundreds of us low rep which have had a critical thought about it, and reflected that saying thanks and please is useless. High rep still have 20 edit reviews per day. They can't really change the way edits remove thanks and please from posts.

Comment: Hi.  I have read your input, and disagree with it.  Hope that helps!

Comment: So by this metric, because many users bad off-topic questions every day, we should accept that as the new social norm? Just because people do not follow the rules does not mean that the rules are then invalid.

Comment: Hi Tiny - yes, that's exactly correct. You've made it sound "strange" - but look at it this way: An example is the possibly absurd rule about "not recommending packages". As you probably know on SO, many questions lean through this concept: the rule probably existed to stop tedious product recommendations; but in much of ios/android development it's "all about" which package you use for some problem (ranging from cocoapods to networking libraries - whatever). People flaunt this "silly rule" continually: in time, the silly rule will be revised...

Comment: ..in that example, just as the "law" in the "real" word is a living thing, the example rule in question will eventually be revised (perhaps, let's say, to something more along the lines of "no questions that purely seek product recommendations, although of course it's ok to speak about common packges" .. or whatever works). So while you make it sound "silly" in the way you phrase it, Tiny, it is, quite simply, exactly how the overall system works.

Comment: Hi people please stop voting to delete content you disagree with. In fact having dissenting opinions available is valuable. Also, this post directly answers the question - 'nuff said.

Comment: I can only add one thing: mixing *normative description* with *normative prescription* is why so many people have trouble with the law. While both are *normative*, they *ain't* and *shouldn't* be equal. It's an issue discussed thousands of times by both politicians, philosophers, linguists etc. Just because an error is common doesn't make it less of an error... or maybe those [fifty million Frenchmen](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum) were right?

Comment: Hi Vax.  Really neither of those concepts apply here.  S.O. is a business started by some people, the owners, to make money to buy diapers and bread. That's all it is. They own it and can do anything they like with it.  As it happens, the business model is a "pro-sumption" one, to use the usual Toffleresque term: the "consumers" actually "produce" the content.  (Just like many of the large dotcoms of our day.) Given that, pro-sumption sites always offer the users (/producers) a kind of vibe that they! get to make the rules themselves.....

Comment: .... (by a kind of consensus, voting, admin privileges, Verified Purchase Review, or whatever.) The question of whether or not it is actually " GOOD " to add sign-offs on posts, is a kind of third-order question at best.  ("Good" in what sense? in the actual purpose of the business, ie, Make Money for the owners?  "Good" in the sense of "societal good"?  Who knows. We can't even answer questions like 'should it be free to download led zepplin'.)  The "democratic fallacy" {as an aside, if you think you've solved all the philosophical issues surrounding that, that's cute) is not so much...

Comment: ...irrelevant here as just "totally irrelevant here". You might as well talk about such issues in relation to social norms that pervade gameplay in popular RPGs.  Indeed, you might as well talk about that because it's an identical situation - !  OF COURSE all you have to go on is popular motions and behaviours. If almost every single user felt (unlike yourself) that sign-offs were a good thing, the site owners would (one assumes) go with that, on the basis of supporting the overall (rather comic, really) "make pro-sumption content creators feel they have control!" vibe.  What else is there?

Comment: I don't really follow you, but cheers for now.

Comment: @JoeBlow Solid point, thanks. But then your curly brace was unbalanced...