# High reputation users answering totally off-topic question

Tags: discussion

What is the best course of action when you see high reputation users answering really off-topic question?

For instance:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523818/if-i-will-not-always-use-os-x-should-i-not-use-xcode

Question was closed as primarily opinion based, but it has two answers and as such it is locked down (OP cannot delete it, AFAIK)

Since answers were posted by high reputation users, down voting might not be sufficient. And from my experience flagging answers as low quality would be declined.

Linked questions:

[Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions)

[Downvoting good answers on bad questions, helpful or not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274919/downvoting-good-answers-on-bad-questions-helpful-or-not)

While above questions and answers provide additional guidance that can relate to this particular question, I am not asking whether it is ok to down vote bad answers, but what can you do when really unsalvageable off-topic question is answered by high reputation users that should know better.

Meta-effect certainly helped in removing particular off-topic question, but if we need to take such things to meta, then IMO real system is somewhat broken.

Comment: Not sure the "high reputation" is relevant,,,certainly they should know better but **this** question should, perhaps, be more generic and just refer to answers in general.

Comment: Getting it closed is the first stage to getting it deleted.  It is well on its way.

Comment: ...and it's gone. Meta effect at it's best. The OP's question still stands.

Comment: @Paulie_D I think that for users with lower reputations, downvoting is good enough message.

Comment: I've seen this behavior a number of times, really irritating in general, but much more so when it's an active user with more than 20k rep. You're right, down votes usually aren't sufficient to change the user's behavior in these cases, often the reason the user climbed to such a high rep is because they answer everything without regard to quality.

Comment: The 'problem' basically has the same root as this question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301016/what-to-do-when-a-high-rep-user-is-willfully-breaking-site-rules-meta-consensus - basically, what *can* you do against users of any reputation that willingly ignore site rules and conducts and just answer off-topic or duplicate questions every chance they get?

Comment: Huh, apple developers.  Interesting.

Answer (score 12):

Reputation never matters in judging the merits of the post.

If the answer is wrong, low quality or offensive/rude use any of the moderation options you have:

- down vote to indicate that the answer is not useful
- edit if you can make it more clear
- leave a comment if you think the OP needs to put more love in it
- close vote the question if that is warranted
- delete vote the question if no value will be lost
- flag as low quality if there is nothing to salvage
- flag as Not an Answer if it is nothing more then a [See here](http://www.google.com) link

Everybody is held against the same high standards. Reputation, username, avatar, location to name a few are never of influence on how to moderate the post.

The question can be deleted, either by the OP or by users with delete votes as the question is down voted and closed.

Answer (score 11):

> OP cannot delete it, AFAIK

Since there are no upvoted answers, they can actually delete it.

Also since the question has a score of less than -3 other users with the deletion privilege can vote to delete it.

> Since answers were posted by high reputation users, down voting might not be sufficient.

Why? Downvoting is a good tool to indicate answers that are off the policies, regardless of the answerers reputation levels.

Comment: So actually, downvoting can help... good to know.

Comment: Yes...but that doesn't address one point of the OP's question...which is how to modify the answerer's behaviour

Comment: @Paulie_D Downvoting of course.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, answerers behaviour is part of the problem here.

Comment: OP can't delete if there is more than one answer, regardless of votes/score.

Comment: Also "OP can't delete it if there are any upvotes" doesn't just mean a negative posted score. The posted score is a combination of upvotes and downvotes, even if it's at `(-3)`, it could be (+1/-4)` in which case it cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the answerers just disagree with the closure. As long as a question is not closed they kind of have a right to attempt to answer it.

Please keep in mind that closed questions can be reopened, especially if they get improved.

On the other hand I guess that answers to bad question are rarely good. If they are one should strive to improve the question. If they aren't one should just downvote them.

Comment: I guess that you haven't seen the question nor the answers. It was totally off-topic question asking for IDE recommendations, and one of the answerers stated in beginning of his answer that question is completely off-topic. This is case of unsalvageable question where two high reputation users (above 20K) jumped in and posted equally bad answers.

Comment: BTW, you can have good answers to bad questions, and if the question is not completely off-topic such answers can provide valuable resource to others, even if question itself is not stellar one.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar You're right. I was answering more from general principles without having studied the particular examples. In general I think that downvoting is sufficient since it indicates a bad answer. If however you have a good answer than in my opinion most often the question can also be made ontopic, so I usually concentrate then on salvaging the question and most often I succeed. However in the majority of cases the answers are not good and I just downvote and move on.