# Thanks being edited in to post and got approved

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

As you can see in the following [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55158567/2) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDmXa.png)):
[image]

The edit was approved and the following [2 edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55158567/revisions) by 1 3k rep user and 500k rep user. Still, left the non-brevity around? Am I missing something here? Or has the consensus changed to allow non-brevity? In fact, I've seen several posts being edited like this.

Related: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), 
[Editing for Brevity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37439/editing-for-brevity?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: The edit was actually [approved by the 3k rep user, then accepted by the post author.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22461863). The 500k rep user saw it afterwards and just changed the "advanced" to "advance." Though that's not important, what is important is that the suggested edit was very bad and should not have been approved, and the second user should have just eliminated the "help us" nonsense.

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/301022/7795130) suggests bringing such issues to the attention of moderators, so a moderator flag on the question describing the issue with the edits is probably the way to go. This question might actually be a duplicate of that one: [What to do when a high-rep user is willfully breaking site rules/meta consensus?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/301016/7795130)

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure if flagging with a custom mod flag was the choice here. Since previously I was told that mod has *many* thing more important than a random flag.

Comment: Take into account that suggested edits suffer from race conditions sometimes; submitting a suggested edit after someone else also edited a post. User A here added backticks, User B with 2k+ rep or the post owner *removed* “thanks”. Resulting in a suggested edit that **looks** like it added the thank you.

Comment: The suggested edit here was created during the grace period so it could be that the OP had removed the thanks after the other user started editing the post to create a suggested edit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If there are other similar edits, which are preferable? Custom mod flag one of them and link several links and ask for further investigation for each of them? Or is there any other way?

Comment: @Mukyuu: if you see a user make a pattern of bad edits (adding thanks), flag one case and say that they have a pattern. Linking to some example suggested edits would be really helpful but us moderators can pull up the suggested edits ourselves too to verify.

Comment: Not only is that edit the polar opposite of good (literally every change it makes is the sort of thing that should be edited _out_), but that user's suggestion history is terrible. A word from a mod is definitely called for.

Comment: An edit that ADDS a thank you?? Truly baffling.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to flag bad reviews to my knowledge.

It is good idea to check if this is an isolated incident or if the editor routinely suggests bad edits. To check recent edits go to

> user's account -> activity -> all actions -> suggestions.

If you see pattern of bad edits (like in this case - edits look similar - minor spelling fix, add misspelled thank you and some code formatting to regular text) then flag the post you were reviewing with "in need of moderator intervention" and describe what you've found and links to questionable edits.

If this is single case of either edit or approval - let it go, possibly fix the post yourself (if the post worth it).

**For this particular edit**

I don't see how that edit "improved" anything:

- bogus single quote in title added
- regular words wrapped in code formatting
- added misspelled thank you note

None of this made the post any better and definitely could not have added what the OP tried to solve the problem (instead of "I tried to do a lot but did not succeed in", which could have been removed by the edit just fine).

I would flag the post with "low quality edit by editor {link to edit} was approved. The editor routinely adds thank you notes and unnecessary code formatting {more links to suggested edits}".

Comment: Is it viable to custom mod flag one by one or just one of them and give some examples linking to some LQ suggestion edit which got approved ?

Comment: @Mukyuu I use single flag (with links to multiple edits) - it is already enough effort to write one good flag explanation, I don't have desire to write multiple for the same set of edits.

Answer (score 3):

Something could have happened where edited out the thanks message, but the other user put in an edit that changed the spelling of `advanced` to `advance`, which put the thanks message back in.

But no, thanks messages should not be included in questions as they are unnecessary and don't contribute to the content. I often edit questions where there are these types of messages and I remove them, and those edits are always accepted for me as saying "thanks in advance" is not usually accepted in questions.

Answer (score -30):

I personally would like to see "Thanks" allowed and used.  It only takes a few characters, and it really makes everything more polite.  Also, it has some utility:  If one sees "thanks" in a post, it is likely [but by no means certain] that the solution works, at least for the person who added the "Thanks".

Comment: And how useful is this, "Thanks" in a source like an encylopedia, or wiki article?

Comment: If you're thanking an answer, you should be upvoting instead. And having "thanks" in a post does *not* make the answer any more likely to work than it would be otherwise.

Comment: Definitely not. SO is not a forum for chatting, its about finding help and leaving that help for everyone else to use. It's focused on the *best content possible*. A unnecessary message does not contribute to the content. We have Upvoting.

Comment: I don't ask for 'help' when accessing wiki, therefore one doesn't put thanks there (I rarely go behind the scenes but if I was collaborating with someone, I would put thanks on the behind the scenes pages).  In any event, this is why some people will continue to view SO as unfriendly (in general).  It doesn't hurt anybody to take a few minutes to say thanks

Comment: It detracts from the core mission: ask questions, get answers.  If people have to wade through irrelevant texts like, "Thanks", "Helped me", "Good one", etc., etc., it makes it harder to find the information that is actually useful.  Everyone thinks SO is unfriendly, but nobody can deny that finding an answer here is far better than anywhere else.

Comment: @JosephDoggie I rather have some people view us as unfriendly then to give up our effort to be a well maintained, high quality and valuable resource for many visitors that are not looking for being tanked or welcomed, they are here because they are looking for an answer. That is our goal here. If that doesn't align with some people, fine. But let's not mis-align with the millions that rely on the content we curate here.

Comment: And if it had said *Thanks* maybe, maybe it would be fine in 6 to 8 years but in the screenshot it shows *Thanks in advanced* ... What does that even mean?

Comment: Looks like the SO community has once again confused the "This answer is not useful" button for a "I don't like this opinion" button. What is this, Reddit?

Comment: @Orion: This answer is not useful, because it is superficially rehashing arguments that were examined in considerable detail and thoroughly rejected quite a few years ago. It is also not useful because it argues for a policy most Meta regulars consider to be counter-productive for the site.

Comment: @Orion this is not an answer (or at least not phrased as such) - so not useful for that. If I read this post as answer saying "you are welcome to add 'Thanks in advanced' " then it is even less useful as following such advice will get you edit-banned.

Comment: I am not saying "you are welcome to add 'Thanks in advanced' -- which should be quite clear.  The fact this was discussed years ago is of course completely irrelevant.  SO has had more posts than I personally care to read that are the equivalent of "why do people view as unwelcoming?" .... Well, banning "thanks" as against the rules certainly doesn't help with that!  Also, my answer appears to be greyed out, which I view as unfortunate (and, frankly, as unwelcoming)

Comment: This continues the perception that curation activities are unwelcoming.  Do you blame a janitor for cleaning up after you, and telling you to remove your shoes because they're muddy?  That's what curation is; you missed the sign that said take off your shoes, and now you're taking it out on the janitor that's trying to keep the place clean.

Comment: IMHO, 'thanks' is not analogous to 'muddy shoes' but that's the whole POV that I've been trying to express ....

Comment: Therein lies the difference; in our perspective, it's noise.  Cruft.  Doesn't belong.  It detracts from what we're trying to build; makes it harder to find an answer or understand a question.  We even have a low quality delete reason for answers that do nothing but say thanks.  That focus on quality is what has made SE so successful.

Comment: On a positive note, I *do* make Stack Overflow (and its related Stack Exchange) sites my go-to place for information.  Let's say I google something Microsoft-related.  I will try to find the Stack Overflow page *ahead* of Microsoft's own page.  Of course, this doesn't speak well of that company's tech support, but I digress.....

Comment: @Orion `Looks like the SO community has once again confused the "This answer is not useful" button for a "I don't like this opinion" button. What is this, Reddit?` It looks like you have confused the presence of downvotes with a belief that you can read the minds of other people and know they are voting because they simply disagree with the answer.

Comment: @DavyM how is an opinion "useful" or "not useful"? It's just an opinion. It's neither. I disagree with JosephDoggie, but I don't feel the need to downvote him because it's just an opinion.

Comment: @JarrodW This "answer" claims that adding thanks is somehow useful without supplying any justification for it. There is [plenty of evidence against doing so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/363946), and simply expressing an unsupported opinion of the air "Well, I believe I'm right" does not contribute to a useful discussion. It also doesn't belong here, arguments about including or excluding thanks should be placed on that meta post I just linked. This here question is about handling an edit in light of existing instruction to remove "thanks." So this answer is not useful for 2 reasons.

Comment: Plus, the final part of the answer is not even clear: `it is likely [but by no means certain] that the solution works, at least for the person who added the "Thanks".` What does this even mean? A question saying "thanks in advanced" is thanking for an answer that hasn't been written yet, so there's no way to claim that the solution works based on the presence of the word "thanks."

Comment: Lastly, I did not make any claim about the answer in my comment as you seem to imply by directing the question `how is an opinion "useful" or "not useful"? It's just an opinion.` towards me. I simply stated that Orion's comment appears to be mind reading. But now that you've questioned how an opinion can be not useful, I realize that this may not have been mind reading, but rather, a lack of imagination. Neither you nor Orion could imagine any other explanation for a downvote on this answer apart from "I disagree," and assumed that nobody can have a valid reason for downvoting because of that.

Comment: I don't think that putting "answer" in quotation marks is very useful or kind.  Again, this is why some users find SO as 'unwelcoming'....

Comment: @JosephDoggie If you could please share why this is an answer to the question, please, correct me. I don't consider it an answer, just an unsupported opinion written in the wrong place. I'm certain that I would feel very unwelcome as well if I jumped into someone else's conversation, made a tangential statement and expected people to take me seriously.

Comment: Because none of this would be an issue if 'thanks' were allowed.

Comment: @JosephDoggie try not to take it personally. There are plenty of people on this site are quite kind and helpful. While I disagree with you on this subject I appreciate the sentiment you wish to convey. Politeness is a virtue, but not necessarily "useful" on a SO post, in my opinion ;)