# Edits being approved that should not have been approved

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, specific-edit

[This Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25108961) and [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25108862) (posts btw entirely off-topic) literally introduce "**Thanks**" to the posts and otherwise just randomly format words. The user in question has done this multiple times today already.

Yet, both edits were approved - what should be done in such a case? I feel like it doesn't even matter to review stuff if this is getting through.

Comment: I think when the community approve, it means that one user picked the "improve the edit" and removed the thanks.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It should have been *Reject and Edit* at best

Comment: If without the "Thanks" the edit is good then it's better to do "Improve edit" and remove the thanks

Comment: by the way, the "Thanks" was already there in the second post

Comment: @TemaniAfif You really think so? The English was not improved, only equally badly rewritten and the formatting is all over the place.

Comment: Flag it for a mod to handle. Us normal users can't (or shouldn't) interact with the user over this.

Comment: @leonheess Temani didn't say they were, they said *"if"*

Comment: @NickA True that

Comment: I just think encouraging this kind of edit is not what we should be doing but I guess that's just my opinion.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: The initial revision of the second post did not include *Thanks*. It was introduced by the suggested edit, in both cases.

Comment: @Larnu: no, they were approved by Community because a reviewer decided to use the 'edit' button, which includes an implicit approval. If you look at each review you'll see the *Edit* decision on each.

Comment: It's a pity that those actions were used, because it means I can't now, as a moderator, revert the approval. That's only an option if the suggested edit is still the most recent revision of the post. I've reverted a few older such edits, however.

Comment: I've come across a couple of similar edits (just ***adding*** "Thanks") in the last few days - seems to be the latest trend. Edits that just **remove** "Thanks" generally get my "approval" though.

Comment: Also, since reading posts similar to this one on Meta, I'm now sometimes finding it hard to choose between "Improve Edit" (thus rewarding the earlier editor) and "Reject and Edit" (= no rep. reward). Balance is generally between more undoing versus more re-doing.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yeah I've seen a few of these, some of the ones I think *might* get approved I'll reject and edit with a minor fix purely to *ensure* it gets rejected

Comment: @NickA That's probably what I will end up doing, but it feels like I'm gaming the system to force my opinion through.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just went through his edit history. Thanks for going through as well and handling these *textual conflicts*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see a "thanks" here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25108862 ...

Comment: They're called robo-reviewers and they accept trash like this all the time. Don't ask me why, I have no idea. Probably badge-farming.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: A ban was given to me because of this, but if you look closely at the edit I did (at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59769983/revisions) I **removed** the "Thanks" part. I left the rest, as I felt it to be mostly neutral (and English is not my native tongue, so sorry if I haven't seen an obvious bad change). I do not understand why I am penalized hence...

Comment: @TemaniAfif ah, I indeed missed that the OP had a *Thanks* in there at the end of the wall of text. My apologies.

Comment: @TemaniAfif "it means that one user picked the "improve the edit" and removed the thanks." I did that indeed, like I said I felt the rest was ok but removed the Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I didn’t hand out review bans over this; I’ll ask the moderator that did to see if they want to chip in.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I did something wrong (like using the "Improve Edit" button) I would be happy to understand what and how to do better next time, but here I see only myself removing a "Thanks" and getting banned for that until February 17th from all edit queues on SO, and I completely miss the relationship between my action and such a ban. So clues are welcome. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @S.S.Anne If that is me you are calling a "robo-reviewer", in that specific queue I was (I do not have access to any of the pages anymore so can quote specific numbers) far over 1000 reviews (In fact, I see on the global board I had 2287 reviews in that queue) , so there are then no more badges to acquire, hence my motivation is not there. Anyone (except me now, the irony) can also look at my past list of edit reviews (and in other queues) and see if I "accept trash like this all the time".

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, The edit should have been rejected. 1) It added incorrect code formatting (see [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text), 2) It harms the grammar, the last sentence became _"I want to implement it in my app any source guide online for that."_ which is clumsy at best, and 3) It's off-topic (an offsite resource request). Take all these away, as well as the bold Thanks you removed, and you're left with adding bold to a single word. Reject was the correct choice.

Comment: @Bryan "The edit should have been rejected" If so, does this single review error justifies a one month ban? Specifically when the ban does not give any useful reasons (like you did), and just points to this meta discussion? I am sure it is easy to find passing edit reviews of incorrect code formatting, or clumsy text, or off-topic (this would be for the close queue, not the edit one), does any editor gets a one month ban each time?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek no, the review ban was just to get your attention here. Since it has served its purpose I've lifted the review ban. Do keep in mind what was discussed above, including do not improve edit or approve minor edits, especially those that doesn't make an off-topic post become on-topic

Comment: @PatrickMevzek No, I was just making a joke. I was not implying that you're a robo-reviewer.

Comment: Yes, [it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24567403) [is](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24567450) [nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24536369) [new](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24547917).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thanks being edited in to post and got approved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381357/thanks-being-edited-in-to-post-and-got-approved)