# What is the purpose of making trivial edits to closed questions?

Tags: discussion, edits, closed-questions

I've noticed recently that the "Reopen" queue on SO is overflowing (no pun intended) with questions brought there by some trivial edits, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59927124/revisions)

[image]

Normally, if such an edit came up in the suggested edit review queue, it would be rightfully rejected as "no improvement". Here it originates from a high-rep user and is not subject to review.

The question was closed a week ago and edited today, so it can't be a race condition.

What is the goal of such edits?

Comment: Why would such an edit be made in the first place when it edited items that should have been completely removed from the post.

Comment: gotta pump up those numbers

Comment: Must be [some kind of an experiment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60021301/revisions) -- I can't see how this would be done seriously.

Comment: I want to believe a 623k user would know better than that, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what else could be going on here.

Comment: @JoeW Looking at their edit history, they never remove salutations/"thank you"s from posts. In fact, I've seen several edits where they specifically just edit, "Thank you in advanced." to "Thank you in advance" (including removing the period).

Comment: It's also a fairly recent closure, so it wasn't yet obvious that the OP wasn't going to make a good edit attempt to get it re-opened. (I realize that's rare but I still believe we shouldn't be taking that opportunity from people with bad/trivial edits.)

Comment: Would this invite @marc_s to repond?

Comment: @mustaccio no, only users who interacted with a post (including non-autocmpleting editors/close voters) can be pinged... Flagging the edit on other hand may attract some attention from mods thus indirectly inviting the user to meta do discuss...

Comment: I moderator flagged such obviously inappropriate behaviour in the past & was declined with the disgusting reason that the user contributes a lot of good so nothing's going to be done. PS You can contact editors using @ on the posts they edited or just commenting on some post of theirs.

Comment: Maybe the editor wanted to find out, if the reopen queue reviewers are paying attention. Some kind of user made audit. Congratulation, you passed the audit.

Answer (score 18):

It's not only a trivial edit, it's a harmful edit.

- It doesn't solve any problem in the post at all
- By "fixing" details on fluff that should actually be removed it reinforces the wrong message (that fluff is actually fine, but you should take care in spelling your fluff correctly)
- By virtue of being the first edit on a closed post **it will push it into the reopen queue**.

Of course, the post is unsalvageable and would never be reopened, but it will take a place in the reopen queue. **Three users already had to review the question on the reopen queue**.

One would hope that an editor with so much reputation and experience should know that using delete votes is more appropriate here than wasting (their and other's) time in trivial, useless edits.

Editing stuff that should actually be deleted is a waste of the editor's time at best. But it can also be detrimental.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the goal of such edits?

**Nothing.** The editor just had different values or indifference to how we're [***expected***](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) to [***curate***](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it).

**Solution:**

Just edit out any leftover or improve anything that could be improved which aren't dealt with.

<sub>Just FYI it's not the first time he does this ([related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381357/thanks-being-edited-in-to-post-and-got-approved))</sub>

Comment: Sort of related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/252077#252077